# Spring Data Rest Unexpected behavior on GET

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

Im in a Spring boot project with Spring Data Rest, i have implemnt a get with the data rest and its work fine:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel="categorias-perguntas",path="categorias-perguntas")
public interface CategoriaPerguntaRepository extends CrudRepository<CategoriaPergunta, Long>{}
```

After i have implemnted a normal RestController:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController("motoristas")
public class MotoristaController {...}
```

with one get:

```
@GetMapping
@ResponseStatus(code=HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public Motorista buscaMotoristaPeloUsuario(@RequestParam(value="idUsuario") Long idUsuario) {
    return this.motoristaService.findByUsuarioId(idUsuario);
}
```

After implementing this controller, my DataRest "/categorias-perguntas" has stopped working, and returning:

```
"error": "Bad Request",
"exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException",
"message": "Required Long parameter 'idUsuario' is not present",
"path": "/categorias-perguntas"
```

But "/categorias-perguntas" dont have this parameter.
Why my RestController are change the Data Rest Resource behavior ?

Comment: Try hitting your backend with the URL - /categorias-perguntas?idUsuario=1L.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add some path to your `MotoristaController` f.e. by adding class level annotation  @ResquestMapping('/motorista')` and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem getting off the  @ResquestMapping annotation and put path on @GetMapping("motoristas"). But i dont know why problem get in.